# Loop through to change parameter in Python 2.7

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, dynamic, parameter-passing

So I have this code that is creating an output in Excel.
What I want to do now is get the parameters (lid) in payload to loop through a list of other ID's

This list is stored in a txt file.

can anyone modify my code to show me how to do that please?
The text file has values
1654,
3457,
4327,
1234

(can also hard code these somewhere in the script if it is easier)

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import csv
import collections
import itertools
try:
    import requests
    from requests import exceptions
    import base64
    import json
except ImportError as e:
    import requests
    from requests import exceptions
    import base64
    import json
    print ("Import Error: %s" % e)

API_TOKEN = u''

b64token = base64.b64encode(bytes(API_TOKEN))


REST_BASE_URL = u'https://visdasa.dsds.com/rest/'

# API URL request examples (choose one)
REST_URL = u'rawdata/'

FULL_URL = REST_BASE_URL + REST_URL

def retrieve_data(api_url):

    try:
        #connect to the API and retrieve data
        bauth_header = {'Authorization': 'Basic '+b64token.decode('UTF-8')}
        payload = {'start': '2014-08-01T00:00:01', 'stop': '2014-  8-01T23:59:59','category': 'ots','lid': '9263'}

        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=bauth_header, params=payload)
        # check the api response
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:

            # Convert from json data
            json_data = json.loads(response.text)


            Header_String = "ID", "Site Name", "Network ID", "Network Lablel", "Company Branch ID", "Comapany Label","Count", "timestamp", "ots_duration", "notsure1", "notsure2"
            for location_row in json_data["data"]["locations"]:
                Location_string = (location_row["id"], location_row["label"], location_row["site"]["network"]["id"],location_row["site"]["network"]["label"],
                                location_row["site"]["id"], location_row["site"]["label"])

            try:

                with open('C:\\Users\\teddy\\Desktop\\party\\test.csv', 'w') as wFile:
                    writer = csv.writer(wFile, delimiter=',')
                    writer.write(Header_string)
                    for row in json_data["data"]["raw_data"]:
                        writer.writerow(row)

            except IOError as e:
                logger.error("I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
                print( "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))  


            else:
                    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
            # If not successful api call the throw an error
            raise requests.RequestException("Error with the api. Status code : %i \n Json response: %s"
                                            % (response.status_code, json_data))

    except (requests.exceptions.ProxyError, requests.RequestException) as e:
        print (e)


def main():

    #retrieve_data(FULL_URL, PROXY_SETTINGS)
    retrieve_data(FULL_URL)
    sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just pass all the lid values as a parameter to your retrieve_data function.

```
def retrieve_data(api_url):
```

would become

```
def retrieve_data(api_url, lid_value):
```

You would remove the hardcoded `lid` section of your payload so the payload would look like this

```
payload = {'start': '2014-08-01T00:00:01', 'stop': '2014-  8-01T23:59:59','category': 'ots'}
```

Then on the next line you can add

```
payload['lid'] = lid_value
```

In your main function you could then loop through the values in the text file.  Here is a simple loop with a list.

```
def main():
    lid_values = ['1654', '3457', '4327', '1234']
    for lid in lid_values:
        retrieve_data(FULL_URL, lid)
    sys.exit()
```